# How to efficiently access large objects in Obj-C using objectForKey and objectAtIndex?

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I have a large NSDirectory typically from a parsed JSON-object I can access this object with code like so:

```
[[[[[obj objectForKey:@"root"] objectForKey:@"key1"] objectAtIndex:idx] objectForKey:@"key2"] objectAtIndex:idz];
```

The line might be a lot longer than this.

Can I optimize this code in any way? At least make it easier to read?

This line will also generate a runtime-error if the object does not correspond, what is the most efficient way to avoid that?

Comment: If you're using the right version of Xcode then you can do this: `obj[@"root"][@"key1"][idx][@"key2"][idz]` - slightly more readable (and backwards compatible) but not really the way to go...

Comment: That is very nice! Seems not to work in 4.3.2!?

Comment: Xcode 4.4 is your friend. Developer Preview is available now, final will be available in this month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were using `-objectForKey:` for everything you could use `-valueForKeyPath:`, as in

```
[obj valueForKeyPath:@"key1.key2.key3.key4"]
```

However, this doesn't work when you need to use `-objectAtIndex:`. I don't think there's any good solution for you. `-valueForKeyPath:` also wouldn't solve the problem of the runtime errors.

If you truly want a simple way to do this you could write your own version of `-valueForKeyPath:` (call it something else) that provides a syntax for specifying an `-objectAtIndex:` instead of a key, and that does the appropriate dynamic checks to ensure the object actually responds to the method in question.

Comment: I will make my own `valueForKeyPath`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want easier to read code you can split the line into several lines like this

```
 MyClass *rootObject = [obj objectForKey:@"root"];
 MyClass *key1Object = [rootObject objectForKey:@"key1"];
 MyClass *myObject = [key1Object objectAtIndex:idx];
 ...
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can create some array, that will contain full "path" to your object. The only thing, you need to store your indexes somehow, maybe in NSNumber, in this case you cannot use NSNumber objects as keys in your dictionaries. Then create a method, that will return needed object for this given "path". smth like

```
NSMutableArray* basePath = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"first", [NSNumber numberWithInt:index], nil];
id object = [self objectForPath:basePath inContainer:container];

- (id) objectForPath:(NSMutableArray*)basePath inContainer:(id)container
{
    id result = nil;
    id pathComponent = [basePath objectAtIndex: 0];
    [basePath removeObjectAtIndex: 0];

    // check if it is a number with int index
    if( [pathComponent isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] ) 
    {
        result = [container objectAtIndex: [pathComponent intValue]];
    }
    else
    {
        result = [container objectForKey: pathComponent];
    }

    assert( result != nil );

    // check if it is need to continue searching object
    if( [basePath count] > 0 )
    {
        return [self objectForPath:basePath inContainer: result];
    }
    else
    {
        return result;
    }
}
```

this is just an idea, but I hope you understand what I mean. And as Kevin mentioned above, if you don't have indexes, you can use key-value coding.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it can suit you, but you could also give a try to blocks, I always find them very convenient. At least they made code much more readable.

```
NSArray *filter = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"pathToFind", @"pathToFind2",nil];

NSPredicate *filterBlock = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bind){        
    NSArray *root = (NSArray*)obj;

    // cycle the array and found what you need.
    // eventually implementing some sort of exit strategy

}];

[rootObject filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterBlock];
```